# INFO - Task exited with return code Negsignal.SIGSEGV

Tags: python, airflow, pymssql

The task is load data from MsSql Server using Airflow.

But firstly, I am trying to check connection to MsSQL SERVER.

This is my python script:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.providers.microsoft.mssql.operators.mssql import MsSqlOperator
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import timedelta

default_args = {
        'owner': 'tester',
        }

dag = DAG('mssql_task',
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval = '@daily',
        start_date = datetime(2021, 8, 26),
        catchup=False  
        )

 
conn_orc = MsSqlOperator(
        task_id = "mssql_conn_check",
        mssql_conn_id="mssql_default",
        sql=f"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EQM-CORE.DBO.TEST_TABLE",
        autocommit= True,
        database = 'eqm-core',
        dag= dag
    )
        
conn_orc
```

But dag is failed

```
[2021-09-09 13:54:22,196] {mssql.py:90} INFO - Executing: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EQM-CORE.DBO.SERVICES
[2021-09-09 13:54:22,299] {base.py:78} INFO - Using connection to: id: mssql_default. Host: eqm-lsnr, Port: 1433, Schema: , Login: ETL_USER, Password: ***, extra: {}
[2021-09-09 13:54:22,538] {base.py:78} INFO - Using connection to: id: mssql_default. Host: eqm-lsnr, Port: 1433, Schema: , Login: ETL_USER, Password: ***, extra: {}
[2021-09-09 13:54:23,108] {local_task_job.py:151} INFO - Task exited with return code Negsignal.SIGSEGV
```

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @JoaquínL.Robles I think no, i don't remember. But I achieved my real aim.